# add or append a value in a column to the list in another column in data frame

Tags: r, append, tidyverse, purrr

Here's an example data frame

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
df <- data_frame(abc = letters[1:3], 
                 lst = list(1:3, 1:3, 1:3), 
                 new_data=1:3)
```

which will give the resulting output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    abc       lst new_data
  <chr>    <list>    <int>
1     a <int [3]>        1
2     b <int [3]>        2
3     c <int [3]>        3
```

I would like to append the numbers in `new_data` column to corresponding list in `lst` list-column.

This is how much I got so far:

```
df %>%
  mutate(lst= map(lst, ~ append(.,new_data)))
```

and the result is

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    abc       lst new_data
  <chr>    <list>    <int>
1     a <int [6]>        1
2     b <int [6]>        2
3     c <int [6]>        3
```

I was expecting to have the first list to have `1,2,3,1` and second list to have `1,2,3,2` but both of them are `1,2,3,1,2,3`. In the `mutate` line, `mutate(lst= map(lst, ~ append(.,new_data)))`, `lst` is treated as a single item per row but some how `new_data` is treated as whole column, instead of corresponding value in row.

How can I add just single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `purrr::pmap`, which operates its function as a "zipper" of sorts (similar to R's base `mapply` and python's `zip`).

```
df %>%
  mutate(lst = pmap(list(lst, new_data), ~ append(..1, ..2))) %>%
  str()
# Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ abc     : chr  "a" "b" "c"
#  $ lst     :List of 3
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3 1
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3 2
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3 3
#  $ new_data: int  1 2 3
```

As suggested by thelatemail, you don't need `append` here:

```
df %>%
  mutate(lst = pmap(list(lst, new_data), c))
```

Comment: Why not just `df %>% mutate(lst = pmap(list(lst, new_data), c))` as a translation of `df$lst <- Map(c, df$lst, df$new_data)`? You could use `append` instead of `c` in there too and it will still work.

Comment: So true, thelatemail, so true ... I was too busy fixing the question asked, I forgot to look at the bigger picture.